# A pop up validation form in yii2

Tags: php

I am trying to get who took a book from a database so i want to put admission number so that i can get the details of the stodent; return date etc.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new BooksReturn();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so you need to create SqlDataProvider , that will take admission number and check it with database with Yii::$app->user->identity->(db with student id or something) and then you can return it as a result? or I can't get what you want

Comment: Ok can you put it on my code, so that I can see it. You got me right